# startin a download with playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to start a download of a file with the playwright. right now I have all the info to get to the website and the option to export to the bottom export to excel that downloads an excel but I am having problems getting it to work. here is what I have.

```
  //#cmdExport is the locator of the button
  await page.locator('#cmdExport').click();
  // trying to get over the dialog popup to start the dowload
  page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    console.log(dialog.message());
    await dialog.accept();
    await page.locator('#cmdExport').click();
  });
//don't know what's next
```

this is the flow:

[image: button and HTML code]

[image: download popup]

[image: the website sends this as a loading for the download]

[image: and here is the excel file]

right now with what I read so far the code above the image is all I understand, I don't understand the official documentation of the playwright on the alerts and downloads part.
if someone could help me understand better how is this resolved it would be welcome. I have been all day reading posts and watching videos to know how is this flow made by the playwright but I haven't had any luck understanding this problem.

Comment: This documentation on downloads didn't help you out?
https://playwright.dev/docs/downloads

Comment: after reading it for a couple of hour and taking my time to do it. i made it work. np ty for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [download] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForEvent('download'),
  page.on('dialog', dialog => dialog.accept()),
  await page.locator('#cmdExport').click(),
]);
const path = download.suggestedFilename();
await download.saveAs(path);
```

so the way this was solver was by making a const with the Download like it was said in the official documentation of playwright. then inside the promise. all do the wait for event download. then do the pago on for the dialog.
lastly and the most illogical part for me at least. write the line of code of the button that will be pressed to activate all this flow of events.

then create the path save the file with the name that it was supposed to have with the suggested filename function and save it on the path (that is the main root of your project folder. I was trying to save it on another folder inside the de project, but it threw me some errors so that's all.